# I can't make the score counter work in pygame

Tags: python

I am still new to coding so I am googling a lot, so the code isn't the best. I tried to make a score counter to have points where you unlock new characters (eg. you reach 2000 meters to unlock a car) but I encounter a problem that I don't know how to solve.

This is the code:

```
import pygame
import time

from pygame.locals import (
    RLEACCEL,
    K_UP,
    K_DOWN,
    K_LEFT,
    K_RIGHT,
)

pygame.init()

timer_interval= 500
timer_event = pygame.USEREVENT+1
pygame.time.set_timer(timer_event, timer_interval)

#Define a player calss that extends pygame.sprite.Sprite
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("PixelArtBike.png").convert(), (105,64.2))
        self.surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255), RLEACCEL)
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
        self.speed = 10
        self.score = 0

    def update(self, pressed_keys, screenHeight, screenWidth):
        if pressed_keys[K_UP]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, -self.speed)
        if pressed_keys[K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, self.speed)
        if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(-self.speed, 0)
        if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(self.speed, 0)

        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        if self.rect.right > screenWidth:
            self.rect.right = screenWidth
        if self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.rect.top = 0
        if self.rect.bottom >= screenHeight:
            self.rect.bottom = screenHeight
            Player.score += Player.speed

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == timer_event:
                    self.score += self.speed
```

this is the problem:

```
name 'self' is not defined
  File "C:\Users\ethan\Documents\coder dojo\Python\New folder\Player.py", line 54, in <module>
    self.score += self.speed
    ^^^^
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with Pygame. You just don't know how to use a class. Where is your `Player` object? Something like `player = Player()`? Then you can do `player.score += player.speed`

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an object of a class to be able to access the class variables and methods. Modified code:

```
import pygame
import time

from pygame.locals import (
    RLEACCEL,
    K_UP,
    K_DOWN,
    K_LEFT,
    K_RIGHT,
)

pygame.init()

timer_interval= 500
timer_event = pygame.USEREVENT+1
pygame.time.set_timer(timer_event, timer_interval)

#Define a player class that extends pygame.sprite.Sprite
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("PixelArtBike.png").convert(), (105,64.2))
        self.surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255), RLEACCEL)
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
        self.speed = 10
        self.score = 0

    def update(self, pressed_keys, screenHeight, screenWidth):
        if pressed_keys[K_UP]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, -self.speed)
        if pressed_keys[K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, self.speed)
        if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(-self.speed, 0)
        if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(self.speed, 0)

        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        if self.rect.right > screenWidth:
            self.rect.right = screenWidth
        if self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.rect.top = 0
        if self.rect.bottom >= screenHeight:
            self.rect.bottom = screenHeight
            self.score += self.speed  #Change Player to self

#Create an object of the player class
player = Player()

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == timer_event:
            player.score += player.speed  #Change self to player
```

You need to replace `self` with `player` in the last line of your code. You also need to replace `Player` with `self` in the last line of your `update()` method. I've added comments in the code to indicate the changes.